# matlab to python port optimization

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I have ported a matlab piece of code to python and faced problems with efficiency.

For instance, here comes a snippet :

```
G = np.vstack((Gx.toarray(), Gy.toarray(), Gd1.toarray(), Gd2.toarray()))
```

Here all elements to be stacked are 22500 by 22500 sparce matrices. It dies directly on my Windows 64 bit machine with following error :

```
return _nx.concatenate([atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup], 0)
MemoryError
```

I'm quite new to Python, is there any good article on best practices for such optimization? Any information on how numpy works with memory?

As far as I know sparce matrices stored in some kind of compressed format and take much less space then but take much more time to work with.

Thx!

Comment: Are you expecting a dense or sparse matrix/array as output?

Comment: @Divakar the output is sparse

Comment: The best advise on optimization is - don't try it until your code is working.  The memory error means that one or more of those dense arrays is taking up too much space, much more than the sparse matrices.  That's a hard constraint.  Speed is a soft one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For stacking sparse matrices, you can use [Scipy sparse's vstack function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.vstack.html) instead of NumPy's `vstack` one, like so -

```
import scipy.sparse as sp

Gout = sp.vstack((Gx,Gy,Gd1,Gd2))
```

Sample run -

```
In [364]: # Generate random sparse matrices
     ...: Gx = sp.coo_matrix(3*(np.random.rand(10,10)>0.7).astype(int))
     ...: Gy = sp.coo_matrix(4*(np.random.rand(10,10)>0.7).astype(int))
     ...: Gd1 = sp.coo_matrix(5*(np.random.rand(10,10)>0.7).astype(int))
     ...: Gd2 = sp.coo_matrix(6*(np.random.rand(10,10)>0.7).astype(int))
     ...: 

In [365]: # Run original and proposed approaches
     ...: G = np.vstack((Gx.toarray(), Gy.toarray(), Gd1.toarray(), Gd2.toarray()))
     ...: Gout = sp.vstack((Gx,Gy,Gd1,Gd2))
     ...: 

In [366]: # Finally verify results
     ...: np.allclose(G,Gout.toarray())
Out[366]: True
```

Comment: thanks but what is the difference? is it optimized for sparse matrices?

Comment: @Anton `Gout` is a sparse matrix, so it's optimized for memory. You commented that you are looking for a sparse matrix as output, right?

Comment: `sparse.vstack` works directly with the sparse matrix data. It does not convert the matrices to large dense ones.  But to understand it you have to understand how sparse matrices are stored.

Comment: @Divakar answer helped a lot, I used sparse matricies all over the code and It worked much faster! Thanks!